# Django formset - how to give a different queryset for each form within the modelformset

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a form for a Model - ClinicallyReportedSample, which links to a Sample model.

I am trying to create a formset for ClinicallyReportedSample where, based on a queryset of Sample, a specific amount of forms are displayed so that the user can add data.

Currently, the Sample model has entries, but the ClinicallyReportedSample model is completely empty:

models:

```
class Sample(models.Model):

    request_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    class Meta:
        db_table = "sample"
        unique_together = (('request_number', 'year'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return("%s/%s" %(self.request_number, self.year))



class ClinicallyReportedSample(models.Model):

    sample_id = models.ForeignKey(Sample,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                db_column='sample_id')


    reported = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    evidence = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    ... other fields ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = "clinically_reported_sample"
        unique_together = (('sample_id'),)

    def __str__(self):
        clinically_reported_sample = str(self.sample_id)
        return(clinically_reported_sample)
```

I want ClinicallyReportedSample model forms, within a formset, that relate to a queryset of Sample model.

For example, Sample objects with pk 1, 2 and 3:

forms.py:

```
class BaseCRSFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.queryset = ClinicallyReportedVariant.objects.none()


class CRSForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClinicallyReportedSample
        fields = ('sample_id', 'evidence',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CRSForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So I try to do this using queryset in my formset

views.py:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


    sample_obj = Sample.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3])

    formset = modelformset_factory(
                ClinicallyReportedSample,
                form=self.crsform,
                formset=BaseCRSFormSet,
                extra=3,
            )


    formset = formset(queryset=sample_obj)
```

but this displays as three forms, with ALL Sample objects, the queryset does not work. Is this the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the default Sample queryset to none:

```
class CRSForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ClinicallyReportedSample
        fields = ('sample_id', 'evidence',)

    sample_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sample.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CRSForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then when you make a formset instance manually assign the queryset like so:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    sample_obj = Sample.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3])

    formset = modelformset_factory(
                ClinicallyReportedSample,
                form=self.crsform,
                formset=BaseCRSFormSet,
                extra=3,
            )


    formset = formset(queryset=sample_obj)

    for form in formset:
        form.fields['sample_id'].queryset = sample_obj
```

Note that you'll also have to manually set the queryset in your POST function too otherwise it won't validate.